# How do I restrict the range permitted for the int argument of a method

Tags: java

Say I have a method:

```
public void method(int i) {
    this.value =+ i;
}
```

How can I restrict i to a value greater than x? I understand this can be done outside the method but I would prefer to condition it in the constructor. Would it be something like:

```
public void method(int i; i > x){...};
```

Sorry for not testing this myself, I came up with it as I wrote my query.

Comment: In Java, you would use exceptions and/or asserts

Comment: As far as i know you cannot do in it the method definition but you can do it in the body.

Comment: and that code is not the way

Comment: You can check before the call, check inside the call, use some form of annotation-based pre-/post-condition checking, delegate to the underlying method using a validation/assertion method, etc.

Comment: Personally, rather than just throwing something up on SO, I'd become familiar with the language syntax. There are many documents that cover what is and isn't valid Java.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6816298/is-there-an-beautiful-way-to-assert-pre-conditions-in-java-methods

Comment: Are you trying to use the compound assignment "+="? Because if you do, you have it backwards in your code.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no syntax in Java that can restrict the range of a parameter.  If it takes an `int`, then all possible values of `int` are legal to pass.

You can however test the value with code in the method and throw an `IllegalArgumentException` if `i` is not greater than `x`.

Answer (score 7):

You document the method, and throw an exception if the caller doesn't respect the contract.

```
/**
 * Does something cool.
 * @param i a value that must be > x
 * @throws IllegalArgumentException if i <= x
 */
public void method(int i) {
    if (i <= x) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("i must be > x");
    }
    this.value += i;
}
```

Comment: I would do it throw new IllegalArgumentException(i + " must be > " + x");

Comment: That would make it less clear, IMO: 4 must be > 5: what does that mean? But I agree having the values would be helpful: `throw new IllegalArgumentException("i (whose value is " + i + ") must be > x (whose value is " + x + ")");`

Answer (score 2):

That are no built-in preconditions for method (or constructor) arguments. Either check them at the calling site or within the method (or constructor). You have two options: throw an exception within the method or don't call the method.

Comment: @shekharsuman You parsed it wrong. "Don't call the method" or "throw an exception", parallel to the preceding sentence.

Comment: Well, now parallel, but reversed.