# Within Android code, what suggests the characteristics a program is expecting from a variable?

Tags: java, android

I know if I run a program, it will likely express one way or another: what it is expecting from each variable. But I would like to determine on my own when I read over each page of Android code etc. e.g:

- How could I determine what `size` or `length` an android program is expecting a string array to be?
- Whether an `integer` or `double`, is expected to be *positive* or *negative*?

etc.

Help in this regard would be much appreciated.

Comment: Erm... your own source comments and documentation? This isn't specific to Android either, it's just Java code.

Comment: You are referring to preconditions/postconditions and invariants. There are some annotations you can use and there are other libraries you can use to either document or enforce these. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6816298/is-there-an-beautiful-way-to-assert-pre-conditions-in-java-methods

Answer (score 0):

You can set breakpoints in your code and examine all of the variables when the program pauses. This would give you a general idea of whether the integers were positive or negative, the length and content of the strings, etc. It could be useful if the code was poorly documented.

Assuming you are using Android Studio you can follow this guide:

https://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-studio.html

Comment: As above I was wanting to identify, how to figure out the characteristics a program is expecting from a variable **prior to run-time** e.g. when I am simply reading over a page of Android code. In which case the above **although informative**, *isn't helpful*