# What is the difference between assert object!=null and Assert.assertNotNull(object)?

Tags: java, testing, testng

What is the difference between following two blocks of code?

```
@Test  
public void getObjectTest() throws Exception {
    Object object;
    //Some code
    Assert.assertNotNull(object);
}
```

AND

```
@Test  
public void getObjectTest() throws Exception {
    Object object;
    //Some code
    assert object!=null;
}
```

I do understand that `Assert.AssertNotNull` is a function call from TestNG and `assert` is a key word of Java ( introduced in Java 1.4 ). Are there any other differences in these two ? e.g. working, performance etc

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Well the first case uses the [Assert](http://testng.org/javadocs/org/testng/Assert.html) class from your testing framework and is the right way to go, since TestNG will report the error in an intelligent way.

You can also add your own message to the test:

```
Assert.assertNotNull(object, "This object should not be null");
```

The second case uses the `assert` keyword - it will give you a failure but the stack trace may or may not be understandable at a glance. You also need to be aware that assertions may NOT be enabled.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there is: the assert keyword needs to be enabled using the -ea flag, like

```
 java -ea MyClass
```

The assert can therefor be turned on and off without any changes to the code.

The Assert class will always work instead. So, if you're doing testing, use the Assert class, never the assert keyword. This might give you the idea all your tests are passing, and while actually they don't assert anything. In my 10+ years of coding, I've never seen anyone enable assertions except Jetbrains, so use Assert instead. Or better, use [Hamcrest](http://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/).

Comment: This is being run inside a TestNG platform. TestNG enables assert statements. I'm not sure where you are getting your information.

Answer (score 3):

Talking about Performance:

`assert object!=null;` is a single java statement but `Assert.assertNotNull(object)` will result in calling of Multiple functions of TestNG, so w.r.t. performance `assert object!=null;`  will be slightly better.

Comment: What do you mean by slightly better? Can you please provide some numbers.

Comment: By slightly I mean 'assert object!=null;' will have lesser time but difference will be in milliseconds

Answer (score 0):

The difference is basically the lack of `assert` keyword.
This is the source from testng:

```
static public void assertNotNull(Object object) {
    assertNotNull(object, null);
}

static public void assertNotNull(Object object, String message) {
    assertTrue(object != null, message);
}
```

Please note that the OP used the testng tag!

This is not JUnit's `Assert`!

Some info about java's `assert` keyword:  [assert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3806173/assert-keyword-in-java)