# Asserts removed in Cross-compiled code

Tags: gwt

are asserts removed in the resulting JavaScript of a GWT programm.

Regards,
Stefan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The GWT compiler removes them by default.
However there is a way to tell the compiler to keep them.
See [here](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/FAQ_Client.html#How_do_I_enable_assertions?) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6023309/when-to-use-assert-in-client-common-gwt-code) for more details.